# Load seed data in Rails 3 Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

Till now, i have been using Fixtures, along with a rake task to create some seed data for my database. This worked well, but i suddenly have weird problems(like getting autogen ids of 1,2,3.. in a model and then wrong ids in the join model, making the association not work at all).

Thus, i was wondering what a better alternative is. I've read about different things, as well as the railscast on seeding data.

My data does not really share same pieces of information. It's like separate entries that have to be inserted as they are. For instance, think that i have to insert 1000 users that have particular abilities and skills. This needs some join models and some neat handling of the associations like fixtures do.

So, is there a better than fixtures way to accomplish that ?

Comment: In which form do you have the data available?

Comment: i have it as fixtures now. I want to be able to seed them using similar techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three different options which I use all the time. Let me know what you think and how you get on. All the best.

[Github Gist >>](https://gist.github.com/997746)

Comment: Still, i don't see how the associations are handled in a good manner on this one.

Comment: ChuckJHardy, it's the standard fixtures that i use. You can specify associations there. The question is, can you somehow do it in another more proper manner without fixtures ?

Comment: Any chance you could add a Schema and I will give it a go for you

Comment: Thank you :) I actually wrote my own seeds program that takes care of the whole process in a nice manner. Maybe i will upload to github as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 provides some basic seeding capabilities. See: [http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding](https://web.archive.org/web/20120201013730/http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding)

To summarise:

- You can put any seeding code (in Ruby, using your AR models) in `db/seeds.rb`
- Then run `rake db:seed` to load this (`rake db:setup` does this automatically)

In my seeds file I tend to wrap everything in a transaction, and also define IDs manually (with the assumption that there is no existing data in the DB). Hat tip to the [Prologue gem](https://github.com/quickleft/prologue). Example:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  if User.count == 0 && Role.count == 0
    user = User.new :name => "Admin", :email => "admin@example.org", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password"
    user.id = 1
    user.save!
    user.confirmed_at = user.confirmation_sent_at
    user.save!

    role1 = Role.new :name => 'Admin'
    role1.id = 1
    role1.save!

    role2 = Role.new :name => 'Member'
    role2.id = 2
    role2.save!

    user.role_ids = [1,2]
    user.save!
  end
end
```

There may be better ways of doing this!

In your case you could load up data from a CSV file or something and create the model objects programmatically.

Comment: the problem is that i dont want to define ids manually, but through the associations, as fixtures do.

Comment: You don't **have** to specify IDs. ActiveRecord (or the db) will automatically assign these.

Comment: It's not about ids. It's about associations. For instance, an item may have a user_id. Fixtures provides a way so that i don't have to handle that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ID maybe useful for those default data in database. in @jits case, he doesn't want the ID and the role permission messed up, the IDs are required to be fixed and maintained constantly over several environment or setups.