# Where should I put seed data for RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Where should I put test data that is for RSpec testing purposes only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many things in life, it depends.

1. If you're using [fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures), they live in **test/fixtures**.
2. If you're using factory_girl with RSpec, it can read from a [number
   of places](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage) but **spec/factories/*.rb** seems the most sensible
   place to put them.
3. If you're using something else, check the documentation for your
   other fixture or factory gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fixtures` ([1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)) if the data is simple or go to `factory_girl_rails` gem ([2](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails)) if you need something more sophisticated.

Also you can create a `rake task` for populating your database.

Please consider look for similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167165/load-seed-data-in-rails-3-project)